# MVC 5, Two SiteMap Providers in a app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, mvcsitemapprovider

Have two sitemaps in a mvc 5 app, but only the default(mvc.sitemap) is working, added the new provider in web.config.

Tried to use the new one as default but still app was picking up the default one, and if I remove that file totally then error is showing up(In the views I have retrived the page titles from the sitemap, so Pagetitle attribute showing error as there is no sitemap)? 
Any suggestions?

Customer SiteMap is not detected

```
 <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="MvcSiteMapProvider" type="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultSiteMapProvider, MvcSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="~/Mvc.Sitemap" securityTrimmingEnabled="true" cacheDuration="5" enableLocalization="true" scanAssembliesForSiteMapNodes="true" includeAssembliesForScan="" excludeAssembliesForScan="" attributesToIgnore="visibility" nodeKeyGenerator="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultNodeKeyGenerator, MvcSiteMapProvider" controllerTypeResolver="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultControllerTypeResolver, MvcSiteMapProvider" actionMethodParameterResolver="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultActionMethodParameterResolver, MvcSiteMapProvider" aclModule="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultAclModule, MvcSiteMapProvider" siteMapNodeUrlResolver="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultSiteMapNodeUrlResolver, MvcSiteMapProvider" siteMapNodeVisibilityProvider="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider, MvcSiteMapProvider" siteMapProviderEventHandler="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultSiteMapProviderEventHandler, MvcSiteMapProvider" />
    <add name="CustomerSiteMapProvider" type="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultSiteMapProvider, MvcSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="~/Customer.Sitemap" securityTrimmingEnabled="true" cacheDuration="5" enableLocalization="true" scanAssembliesForSiteMapNodes="true" includeAssembliesForScan="" excludeAssembliesForScan="" attributesToIgnore="visibility" nodeKeyGenerator="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultNodeKeyGenerator, MvcSiteMapProvider" controllerTypeResolver="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultControllerTypeResolver, MvcSiteMapProvider" actionMethodParameterResolver="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultActionMethodParameterResolver, MvcSiteMapProvider" aclModule="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultAclModule, MvcSiteMapProvider" siteMapNodeUrlResolver="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultSiteMapNodeUrlResolver, MvcSiteMapProvider" siteMapNodeVisibilityProvider="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider, MvcSiteMapProvider" siteMapProviderEventHandler="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultSiteMapProviderEventHandler, MvcSiteMapProvider" />
  </providers>
```

Comment: Do you have any more details for us? Please show the relevant code / configuration and at least the error messages shown.

Comment: check now, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration that you are showing above is for `MvcSiteMapProvider` v3, but v3 was not compatible with MVC 5.

`MvcSiteMapProvider` v4 is not based on Microsoft's `SiteMapProvider` model, and doesn't require any configuration at all above what is installed by the NuGet package. You should completely remove the `<providers>` section from your web.config as specified in [upgrading from v3 to v4](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Upgrading-from-v3-to-v4) and read the [configuration documentation](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Configuring-MvcSiteMapProvider).

As for using more than one SiteMap, this is an advanced scenario that requires an external DI container to do and the procedure is [outlined here](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Multiple-Sitemaps-in-One-Application).

If you are not already using DI in your application, upgrading to external DI  is as simple as installing one of the `MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC5.DI.<Container Name>` NuGet packages. If you are using DI in your application you will need to install one of the `MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC5.DI.<Container  Name>.Modules`, and then follow the configuration instructions in the readme file that is installed with it.

Note that there are many simpler alternatives to using multiple SiteMaps in order to separate nodes into different groups that are visible together.

- [Security Trimming](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Security-Trimming)
- [Visibility Providers](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Advanced-Node-Visibility-with-ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider)
- Customizing HTML Helper Output (in the `/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/` folder)
- Rolling your own HTML Helper (see a demo [here](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/issues/363))